# Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App'). No puedo resolver ese error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

INDEX JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

> APP JSX

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(){
    return(<div>Curso React</div>)
}
```

Cuando compilo me dice lo siguiente:

```
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').
```

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Intenta con `export default function App()...`, [doc export ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_the_default_export)

Answer (score 0):

no se si ya lo habras resuelto...
Pero creo que el problemas es que te falta esta linea de codigo al final de App.js

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.